# InvalidOperationException:The property has a temporary value while attempting to change the entity's state to 'Modified

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, ef-core-2.0

i have two classes with one to many relation

```
public class Foo
{
    public int FooId { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public int FooId { get; set; }
    public Foo Foo { get; set; }

    public int BarId { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I want to edit a `Foo` entry and need to add new `Bar`

```
var foo = _context.Foos.Include(b => b.Bars).FirstOrDefault(x => x.FooId == 8);
foo.Description = "changed";
_context.Entry(foo).State = EntityState.Modified;
foo.Bars.Add(new Bar() { Description = "new one",FooId=8,Foo=foo});
foreach (var b in foo.Bars)
        _context.Entry(b).State = b.BarId == 0 ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;
_context.SaveChanges();
return View();
```

I get error:

> InvalidOperationException: The property 'BarId' on entity type 'Bar' has a temporary value while attempting to change the entity's state to 'Modified'. Either set a permanent value explicitly or ensure that the database is configured to generate values for this property

Comment: Apparently your logic is incorrect, but why you ever manipulate `State` in this scenario?

Comment: There's no need to modify the state here. `Add` will set the state to `Added` already, and since you're not actually changing any of the existing `Bar` instances, you should leave their state as `Unchanged`. Otherwise, you're issuing update commands for no reason.

Comment: FWIW, you also don't need to set the state on your `Foo` instance either. It is already tracked by EF, so when you changed the property, it automatically changes its state to `Modified`.

Comment: @chirs Pratt can u give me some useful link for EF core one to many and many to many save and edit